# pandas.DataFrameのdropメソッドをfor文を使って回したいのですが、動作しません

Tags: python, pandas

単純に0から4番目の行を削除しようと考えています。

```
for i in range(5):
    df.drop(i)
```

このコードで動作すると思ったのですが、そのあとdfで確認しても変化なしなので参っています。
ネットであれこれ調べて試行錯誤したのですが、見当がつきません...
大変初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、ご教示いただける方がいらっしゃいましたら幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: デフォルトではデータフレームのコピーを返しますので、期待する結果を得るには `inplace` オプションを使います。`df.drop(i, inplace=True)`

Comment: 趣旨とは少し反れますが、目的の動作を for 文を使わずに記述するアプローチもあるようでした。ご質問のコードの場合 `df = df.iloc[5:]` で動くと思います。ご参考までに。[参考リンク(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396903/delete-the-first-three-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.drop()` メソッドは `df` を直接変更はせず行を削除した新たなデータフレームを返すメソッドです。

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)])

In [3]: df2 = df.drop(0)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   0
0  0  # 1行目が残っている: df に変更はない
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9

In [5]: df2
Out[5]:
   0
1  1  # df から 1 行目のみ除いたデータフレームになっている
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

なので1行目から5行目を消すためには `df` を直接操作する(`inplace=True` と設定する)もしくは行の削除結果を変数に代入するべきだと思います。

```py
for i in range(5):
    df.drop(i, inplace=True)
    # または df2 = df.drop(i)
```

ちなみにですが、今回のように5行目までをすべて削除するのであれば、 `df2 = df.drop(range(5))` で `for` を使わずに削除することもできます。